# Convert Fortran real to character without blanks

Tags: fortran, character, trim

Is there a function like `trim()` to apply directly into a real?

I think there is not... So. Is there a way to convert real into character for after apply `trim()`?

My program produce a result as real value (`tf`). Bellow are the code and output:

Code:

```
write (*,'(f13.2)') tf
```

Output:

```
           273.15
```

So, I have tried to convert **tf** into a character (`tfs`) using `write` for after apply `trim()` into `tfs` to remove blank spaces, but unfortunately `trim()` doesn't work anyway, the output was the same!!! See how I do it bellow:

Code:

```
write (tfs,'(f13.2)') tf
write (*,*) trim(tfs)
```

Output:

```
           273.15
```

Before anyone ask why I don't change `w` in `rFw.d`, this is not the issue.

Comment: You say that changing the field width (`w`) in the format isn't the solution, so what is the problem?  If you wrote `(f0.2)`  you'd get no leading whitespace (as you would with `write(*,*) adjustl(tfs)`, but I probably don't understand what you are after.

Comment: You ask if there is anything like trim and then you say trim() does not work anyway, strange indeed. Anyway, with a character you need `adjustl()`, not just `trim()`. And with the real you need a different edit descriptor. Like `f0.2`, see the link.

Comment: `trim()` is named poorly; in other languages it would be called `rtrim()` because it only removes trailing spaces. As @VladimirF notes, you also need `adjustl()` to left-justify the string before trimming, i.e. `trim(adjustl())`.

Comment: @arclight and Vladmir F, it works perfectly! thanks! I'm niewbie in fortran... This was my first ask in stackoverflow, I'm sorry if I was inaccurate in the question...